# Mysql merge 2 count query in one query

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM a WHERE year = 2016 && month = 5 && date = 17 && user = 1
//return 1 row

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM a WHERE year = 2016 && month = 5 && date = 17 && user = 2
//return 0 row
```

I have 2 queries, I need to check user 1 and user 2, user 1 must have 1 row & user 2 must 0 row

My question is: is that possible to merge these 2 queries together

return in 1 row with 2 columns `//return 1, 0`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `sum()` with a condition to count how many times the condition is true

```
SELECT SUM(user = 1) as u1, 
       SUM(user = 2) as u2
FROM a 
WHERE year = 2016 and month = 5 and date = 17
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is called conditional aggregation :

```
SELECT count(CASE WHEN `user` = 1 THEN 1 END) as usr1_cnt,
       count(CASE WHEN `user` = 2 THEN 1 END) as usr2_cnt
FROM a
WHERE year = 2016 and month = 5 and date = 17
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT SUM(user = 1) AS user1, SUM(user = 2) AS user2
FROM a 
WHERE year = 2016 AND month = 5 AND date = 17
```

The first field of the `SELECT` clause returns `user = 1` occurrences, whereas the second field  returns `user = 2` occurrences.

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
    SELECT
    (
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM a 
    WHERE year = 2016 && month = 5 && date = 17 && user = 1
    ) AS usr1,
    (
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM a
     WHERE year = 2016 && month = 5 && date = 17 && user = 2
    ) AS usr2
```

Comment: Why select from the table twice? this can be done in one select.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this one:

```
SELECT SUM(user = 1) as user1, 
       SUM(user = 2) as user2
FROM a 
WHERE year = 2016 and month = 5 and date = 17;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT * from (
SELECT COUNT(*) count1 FROM a WHERE year = 2016 && month = 5 && date = 17 &&  user = 1) aa,
(SELECT COUNT(*) count2 FROM a WHERE year = 2016 && month = 5 && date = 17 && user = 2) bb;
```

Comment: Why select from the table twice? this can be done in one select.

Comment: But I want to do it with two table so.

Comment: This is an unnecessary calculation!